# Gradient boosting provides constant forecast values

Tags: r, xgboost, r-caret, forecast

I am trying to forecast a time series using the machine learning method gradient boosting in R but I am facing an issue.

I have separated the data into a training set (75 obs) and a test set (17 obs) and fitted a XGB model using the `caret` package. When I compare the plots of my predicted values against real values, I obtain something I would say acceptable. However, the issue happens when I try to forecast for the next 12 quarters, the model keeps returning me constant forecast values, which is basically a perfectly horizontal line when plotting.

First of all, I am totally aware that I should not expect great results as I only have 92 observations and 10 independent variables but that is what we were provided with for this work. Is it normal to only have a constant value though?

Here is my code to see if I did something wrong:

```
#Load data
a = diff(log(UnempRate$LRUN64TTBEQ156S))
b = diff(log(GDP$CPMNACSCAB1GQBE))
c = diff(log(URateUS$UNRATE))
d = diff(log(AirT$PCU481481))
e = diff(log(DGoods$PITGCD02BEQ661N))
f = diff(log(GCredit$QBEGAMUSDA))
g = diff(log(HWage$LCWRMN01BEQ661N))
h = diff(log(Sales$SLRTTO02BEQ661S))
i = diff(log(ActRate$LRAC64TTBEQ156S))
j = diff(log(Imports$Imports))
k = diff(log(Exports$XTEXVA01BEM667S))

dset2 = data.frame(a,b,c, d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k)
```

Then I did this to create a partition

```
#Split data
train = head(dset2,75)
test = dset2[76:92, ]
```

I tuned my XGB model, I am trying to forecast the variable a

```
#XGBoost
grid_tune = expand.grid(nrounds = 1000, max_depth = 8, eta = 0.1, gamma = 0.00, colsample_bytree = 1, min_child_weight = 1, subsample = 1)

train_control = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3, verboseIter = TRUE, allowParallel = TRUE)

xgb_tune = caret::train(x = train[, -1], y = train[,1], trControl = train_control, tuneGrid = grid_tune, method = "xgbTree", verbose = TRUE)
```

And then I run my test on the test set

```
xgb_pred = predict(xgb_tune, test)
ts.plot(test$a, xlab = "Quarters 76 to 92", ylab = "Diff(log()) value", main = "XGB predictions on testing data", col = "#009999")
lines(xgb_pred, col = "red")
```

For which I obtain something, as I said, acceptable but not great:

[image]

Where the blue line is the actual values and the red line the predicted ones

What I did then to forecast is that I added 12 empty rows to my current data frame to use them as `newdata` for `predict()` function and I put my whole 92 observations as a training set:

```
empty_df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 12, ncol = 11))
colnames(empty_df) <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k")
dset3 = rbind(dset2, empty_df)
train2 = head(dset3, 92)
test2 = dset3[93: 104, ]
newtime <- data.frame(Time = seq(93,104, by = 1))
```

I tuned the model:

```
grid_tune = expand.grid(nrounds = 1000, max_depth = 8, eta = 0.1, gamma = 0.00, colsample_bytree = 1, min_child_weight = 1, subsample = 1)

train_control = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3, verboseIter = TRUE, allowParallel = TRUE)

xgb_tune = caret::train(x = train2[, -1], y = train2[,1], trControl = train_control, tuneGrid = grid_tune, method = "xgbTree", verbose = TRUE)
```

And when I predict the 12 empty rows I get the following:

```
xgb_pred = predict(xgb_tune, test2)
```

Results:

```
[1] 0.0709851 0.0709851 0.0709851 0.0709851 0.0709851 0.0709851 0.0709851 0.0709851 0.0709851 0.0709851 0.0709851 0.0709851
```

What did I do wrong? I know that my code is certainly not optimised as I am only a beginner but I really don't understand why I get a constant value. Thanks !

Comment: @KonradRudolph I did and should be readable now, thank you